# windows xp installer cannot create partition in empty slot

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning, mbr

I mainly use Linux, and have 3 partitions (which I do not want to change) on my MBR disk. I have one slot available for Windows XP, for occasional use offline, such as updating my BIOS.

How do I install Windows XP when I only have this one partition slot left? It keeps complaining:

> Setup cannot create a new partition in the space you selected because
>   the maximum number of partitions already exists the disk.

AFAIK, the max limit is 4, but I only have 3, the new partition would be the 4th. Or does it want to create two, one for itself and another one for some reserved space?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved for now:

1. Created a rescue USB with GParted (my linux would not boot after I restarted)
2. Create NTFS partition in empty space
3. XP Installer no longer complains.
4. Create new NTFS (quick) in the same place (I had a hal.dll error if I kept the one from GParted)